# 404 page Not Found Error in codeigniter?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have just started working with codeigniter, now working on admin control of my small project. I have client information list.
[image: Client List]

when i click on view & edit button its giving me  404 error
[image: error page]

i have configured path in application/config/routes.php

```
$route['admin/clients'] = 'admin_clients/index';
   $route['admin/clients/add'] = 'admin_clients/add';
   $route['admin/clients/update'] = 'admin_clients/update';
   $route['admin/clients/update/(:any)'] = 'admin_clients/update/$1';
   $route['admin/clients/delete/(:any)'] = 'admin_clients/delete/$1';
   $route['admin/clients/(:any)'] = 'admin_clients/index/$1'; //$1 = page number
```

code to redirect to edit page

```
<td class="crud-actions">
                  <a href="'.site_url("admin").'/clients/update/'.$row['id'].'" class="btn btn-info">view & edit</a>  
                  <a href="'.site_url("admin").'/clients/delete/'.$row['id'].'" class="btn btn-danger">delete</a>
                </td>
```

Even delete is not working its giving  me the same error.
here is my .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /testing_palace/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

here is my controller file

```
<?php

class Admin_clients extends CI_Controller {

    /**
     * name of the folder responsible for the views 
     * which are manipulated by this controller
     * @constant string
     */
    const VIEW_FOLDER = 'admin/clients';

    /**
     * Responsable for auto load the model
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('admin_client_model');
        if (!$this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')) {
            redirect('admin/login');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Load the main view with all the current model model's data.
     * @return void
     */
    public function index() {

        //all the posts sent by the view
        $search_string = $this->input->post('search_string');
        $order = $this->input->post('order');
        $order_type = $this->input->post('order_type');

        //pagination settings
        $config['per_page'] = 5;

        $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'admin/clients';
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        $config['num_links'] = 20;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul>';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a>';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';

        //limit end
        $page = $this->uri->segment(3);

        //math to get the initial record to be select in the database
        $limit_end = ($page * $config['per_page']) - $config['per_page'];
        if ($limit_end < 0) {
            $limit_end = 0;
        }

        //if order type was changed
        if ($order_type) {
            $filter_session_data['order_type'] = $order_type;
        } else {
            //we have something stored in the session? 
            if ($this->session->userdata('order_type')) {
                $order_type = $this->session->userdata('order_type');
            } else {
                //if we have nothing inside session, so it's the default "Asc"
                $order_type = 'Asc';
            }
        }
        //make the data type var avaible to our view
        $data['order_type_selected'] = $order_type;


        //we must avoid a page reload with the previous session data
        //if any filter post was sent, then it's the first time we load the content
        //in this case we clean the session filter data
        //if any filter post was sent but we are in some page, we must load the session data
        //filtered && || paginated
        if ($search_string !== false && $order !== false || $this->uri->segment(3) == true) {

            /*
              The comments here are the same for line 79 until 99

              if post is not null, we store it in session data array
              if is null, we use the session data already stored
              we save order into the the var to load the view with the param already selected
             */
            if ($search_string) {
                $filter_session_data['search_string_selected'] = $search_string;
            } else {
                $search_string = $this->session->userdata('search_string_selected');
            }
            $data['search_string_selected'] = $search_string;

            if ($order) {
                $filter_session_data['order'] = $order;
            } else {
                $order = $this->session->userdata('order');
            }
            $data['order'] = $order;

            //save session data into the session
            if (isset($filter_session_data)) {
                $this->session->set_userdata($filter_session_data);
            }

            //fetch sql data into arrays
            $data['count_products'] = $this->admin_client_model->count_clients($search_string, $order);
            $config['total_rows'] = $data['count_products'];

            //fetch sql data into arrays
            if ($search_string) {
                if ($order) {
                    $data['manufacturers'] = $this->admin_client_model->get_clients($search_string, $order, $order_type, $config['per_page'], $limit_end);
                } else {
                    $data['manufacturers'] = $this->admin_client_model->get_clients($search_string, '', $order_type, $config['per_page'], $limit_end);
                }
            } else {
                if ($order) {
                    $data['manufacturers'] = $this->admin_client_model->get_clients('', $order, $order_type, $config['per_page'], $limit_end);
                } else {
                    $data['manufacturers'] = $this->admin_client_model->get_clients('', '', $order_type, $config['per_page'], $limit_end);
                }
            }
        } else {

            //clean filter data inside section
            $filter_session_data['manufacture_selected'] = null;
            $filter_session_data['search_string_selected'] = null;
            $filter_session_data['order'] = null;
            $filter_session_data['order_type'] = null;
            $this->session->set_userdata($filter_session_data);

            //pre selected options
            $data['search_string_selected'] = '';
            $data['order'] = 'id';

            //fetch sql data into arrays
            $data['count_products'] = $this->admin_client_model->count_clients();
            $data['manufacturers'] = $this->admin_client_model->get_clients('', '', $order_type, $config['per_page'], $limit_end);
            $config['total_rows'] = $data['count_products'];
        }//!isset($search_string) && !isset($order)
        //initializate the panination helper 
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        //load the view
        $data['main_content'] = 'admin/clients/list';
        $this->load->view('templates/template', $data);
    }

//index

    public function add() {
        //if save button was clicked, get the data sent via post
        if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST') {


        $config['upload_path'] ='public/images/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        //$this->upload->initialize($config);
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

            //form validation
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('client_name', 'client_name', 'required');
            $clientLogo='image';
            $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-error"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><strong>', '</strong></div>');


            //if the form has passed through the validation
            if ($this->form_validation->run()) {

                if (!$this->upload->do_upload($clientLogo)) {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors('<p>', '</p>'));
                    print_r($error);
                }else {
                    //$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                    //print_r($data);
                    $uploadedImg=$this->upload->data();
                    $data_to_store = array(
                        'client_name' => $this->input->post('client_name'),
                        'client_logo'=>  $uploadedImg['client_name']
                    );
                }
                //if the insert has returned true then we show the flash message
                if ($this->admin_client_model->store_clients($data_to_store)) {
                    $data['flash_message'] = TRUE;
                } else {
                    $data['flash_message'] = FALSE;
                }
            }
        }
        //load the view
        $data['main_content'] = 'admin/clients/add';
        $this->load->view('templates/template', $data);
    }

    /**
     * Update item by his id
     * @return void
     */
    public function update() {
        //product id 
        $id = $this->uri->segment(4);

        //if save button was clicked, get the data sent via post
        if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST') {
            //form validation
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('client_name', 'client_name', 'required');
            if (empty($_FILES['clientLogo']['name'])){
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('clientLogo', 'Client Logo', 'required');
            }
            $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-error"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><strong>', '</strong></div>');
            //if the form has passed through the validation
            if ($this->form_validation->run()) {

                $data_to_store = array(
                    'client_name' => $this->input->post('client_name'),
                    'client_logo'=>self::do_upload($_FILES['clientLogo']['name'])
                );
                //if the insert has returned true then we show the flash message
                if ($this->admin_client_model->update_clients($id, $data_to_store) == TRUE) {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', 'updated');
                } else {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', 'not_updated');
                }
                redirect('admin/clients/update/' . $id . '');
            }//validation run
        }

        //if we are updating, and the data did not pass trough the validation
        //the code below wel reload the current data
        //product data 
        $data['manufacture'] = $this->admin_client_model->get_client_by_id($id);
        //load the view
        $data['main_content'] = 'admin/clients/edit';
        $this->load->view('templates/template', $data);
    }

//update

    /**
     * Delete product by his id
     * @return void
     */
    public function delete() {
        //product id 
        $id = $this->uri->segment(4);
        $this->admin_client_model->delete_clients($id);
        redirect('admin/clients');
    }

//edit


}
```

please help me to solve this problem, response will be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Did you have checked the controller by putting exit..?and also did you have loaded view file?

Comment: Also please paste the controller file also

Comment: Please check i have pasted the controller file.

Comment: view  file path is views/
  admin/
    clients/
 add,
        edit,
        list php files
loading the edit file when user clicks on view & edit button

Comment: I removed all the processing things in update function, simple loaded view edit but still  its showing me the same error, i think its routes configuration error,please help me.

Comment: i tried load without the localhost/testing_palace/admin/clients/update ,its loading edit file when i tried by passing id i.e localhost/testing_palace/admin/clients/update/1 its showing 404 error

Answer (score 0):

Use the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: When i tried your code and loaded home page in url without(index.php) its giving me Not found Error.

Comment: Did you enable mod_rewrite in your server?

Comment: Yes, the below code is working for me its similar like yours.RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /testing_palace/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: Sorry i dont know when i tried yours it gave me Not found Error, i dont know the reason behind.

Answer (score 0):

@Noor Fathima

please change the routing conditions

`$route['admin/clients/update/(:any)'] = 'admin_clients/update/$1';
 $route['admin/clients/delete/(:any)'] = 'admin_clients/delete/$1';
 $route['admin/clients/update'] = 'admin_clients/update';
 $route['admin/clients/add'] = 'admin_clients/add';
 $route['admin/clients/(:any)'] = 'admin_clients/index/$1'; //$1 = page number
 $route['admin/clients'] = 'admin_clients/index';`

Comment: Sorry its not working but still getting me same error

Comment: ok, check the config.php file and change the value of 

`$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';`

to

`$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';`

Answer (score 0):

try modifying your update function to pass an argument :

public function update($id = null)

this allows you to either pass a value or null to the function and will work with your routes.

you would then need to delete this :

```
//product id 
$id = $this->uri->segment(4);
```

Comment: I think its not entering into that function when i tried with segment 4.When i tried without segment its working fine.

Comment: if you have the routes :  $route['admin/clients/update'] = 'admin_clients/update'; and  $route['admin/clients/update/(:any)'] = 'admin_clients/update/$1';  along with the code I posted it should enter that function

Comment: however the  $route['admin/clients/update/(:any)'] = 'admin_clients/update/$1'; should come first in the routes file

Comment: $route['admin/clients/delete/(:any)'] = 'admin_clients/delete/$1';
 $route['admin/clients/update'] = 'admin_clients/update';
 $route['admin/clients/add'] = 'admin_clients/add';
 $route['admin/clients/(:any)'] = 'admin_clients/index/$1'; //$1 = page number
 $route['admin/clients'] = 'admin_clients/index'; even this is also not working

Comment: Try this alongside the other changes and ensure that it enters the update function  : $route['admin/clients/delete/(:any)'] = 'admin_clients/delete/$1'; 
$route['admin/clients/update/(:any)'] = 'admin_clients/update/$1'; 
$route['admin/clients/update'] = 'admin_clients/update'; 
$route['admin/clients/add'] = 'admin_clients/add'; 
$route['admin/clients/(:any)'] = 'admin_clients/index/$1';
$route['admin/clients'] = 'admin_clients/index';

Comment: you will need to do the same thing with delete

Comment: I dont know its not entering into function with segment(4),without segment its entering.

Comment: did you change the update  function to read :   
    public function update($id = null)

Comment: Failing this, I would disable my htaccess and then try the same url with the index.php enabled to rule out the htaccess being the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64019/discussion-between-noor-fathima-and-oliverb).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. In your `config.php` use `$config['base_url'] = ''//leave it blank;` and
   `$config['index_page'] = ''// leave it blank;`.
2. Change every `<a href="'.site_url("...")` to this `<?php echo base_url("..."); ?>`.
3. Every links that use `site_url()` change it to `base_url()`.

See if it works. Maybe you can provide your `config.php` too so we can debug more.